# Should employers be able to post "future opportunity" jobs when they have no open positions?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs

I ran across a job is listed on StackOverflow Jobs. At first glance it has skills requirements, benefits information etc and appears to be an actual job listing. I applied to this job and received the response that the company would "keep me in mind for future opportunities" and has NO open positions.

I guess I could have realized this from the job title "Software Engineer (future opportunities)" but I did not, and I gave away my personal information expecting to apply for a specific position at a company.

Is this deceptive?

Should "no current openings but apply for the future" job listings be made more obvious? I personally did not intend to give out my personal information when there was never a job to apply to and will have to be more diligent in the future.

Comment: So they posted a job posting about a future job posting.  Sounds like a meeting about a meeting.  That is, this *shouldn't* be happening.

Comment: I did submit a "report" or whatever the mechanism for this is through the Jobs portal stating how I was confused. Unsure if moderation has come across it yet.

Comment: It could be that a position is not "open" but they will take a good candidate if one applies.

Comment: @Makoto Are you free now to meet to discuss when would be a good time to meet to discuss whether or not this should be allowed?

Comment: @JoeW Could be, but that's just bringing HR jargon to the Jobs website :P. Smoke and mirrors, if you'll hire the right dev then you are pretty much hiring.

Comment: @CodyGray:  If you could Slack me the meeting details I'll get back to you when I'm out of this meeting.

Comment: If in 2 months they contact you asking if you'd like to interview for a position would you be willing to interview?

Comment: I think they need to be clearly marked as such. If they are, I wouldn't have a problem with it.

Comment: If they want to pay SO to post a job that might exist sometime in the future, they should feel free. Sometimes companies want to keep jobs posted for recognition, even if they don't have anything currently open. At least they're being honest, and not just harvesting resumes.

Comment: @Makoto Even worse, a job posting about a future job posting *that may never actually exist*.  There's a fine line to walk here between legit activity and resume harvesting.

Comment: Is this what companies do when they just want to sell your data?

Comment: I might be not remembering this correctly but wasn't one of the founding principles of Jobs that astroturfing like this wouldn't be allowed?

Comment: Says a lot about company culture in my opinion. Sanctionable ad or not, I'd stay away as a principle.

Comment: From the [Jobs rules](https://talent.stackoverflow.com/house-rules): #2 "Job listings must be actual job listings." Enough said? That company is going to think their listing is a massive hit after the meta traffic. If they can see referral URLs I am definitely no longer a candidate for "future consideration" LOL

Comment: Ask them to pay you for the work that you might do in the future.

Comment: > This job is no longer accepting applications.

Comment: My previous employer, after hiring me for their position, left the ad up because they had already paid for it, and "if the right person came along...". I wasn't a fan, but they DID already prepay for like, 6 months of advertising.

Comment: @bruceg Keeping job postings open when you have none, even "for recognition" is not being honest, IMO. The only scenario where this might be acceptable is for positions where they know someone is leaving soon (e.g. they've given their notice or their managers know they are going to fire them) and they want to get a jump start.

Comment: I guess I'm in the minority view on, but I think its a great idea. A good company to me is one that is staffed up well but is looking for the right people. I bet that if someone came along, that would fit well into the company they would make a position to get that person in the door.

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with this. Working for certain digital agences is frequently that: you put your name on a list, when they have the right project, they give you a call. The only issue is whether that kind of job posting is appropriate here, which it's probably not.

Comment: @SteveBennett There is nothing inherently wrong with it no. But SO has clearly defined rules which explicitly disallow this. See the answer from moderation below.

Comment: Isn't that exactly what I just said?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this and I’m sorry this happened to you. Job listings on Stack Overflow must be for actual jobs (open positions). It’s one of a few requirements a company must abide by to be on our platform. Additionally, it must always be clear who the hiring company is and details about a role must be accurate. We’ve taken this job down and our team will be in contact with this customer.

Please continue to report any listings like this that you come across. It’s really helpful as we work to maintain job quality on Stack Overflow