# What can be done about job posters seeking to get free development work?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

Over the past couple of years, I've seen the same job posted numerous times with the same description. The position is described as remote with competitive salary and benefits along with the perks of endless supply of sodas and a free lunch program. I've applied to several times, but I never got a response.

Recently, I applied to it again and I received a phone response from a person who asked me why I was looking for a job and described how great it is to work for them. It sounded like she was reading a script. She told me the hiring process requires completing a test project first before moving forward. She said there was no time limit on it and she would send me the files and instructions.

Within a few minutes after ending the call, I received a zipped up project along with requirements. The project is to design and implement a fairly complete server and client to perform a non-trivial set of file handling operations without the use of outside libraries and must compile in Visual Studio 2017. Normally, a coding test is small, has a well established runtime infrastructure and a testing harness. This one only includes a simple Visual Studio generated code from one of the stock project templates and a vague PDF project instructions.

I suspect the test project is really an attempt to get free development work. While I can't prove my suspicion, the fact that this organization has posted the same job repeatedly over the past two years would lead anyone to form such a conclusion. I would hate to see someone else have their labor stolen because they trusted a job posting on Stack Overflow, a highly regarded site many developers trust.

What actions can we as SO Careers users take when we suspect a job posting is being abused to exploit the good will of job applicants?

Comment: Could the company survive for two years if they need this thing implemented and haven't got it yet?

Comment: @JoshCaswell Of course. It it was a replacement service for their lunch dispatch, they could live very well without it and just use their old software. Just an example, but enough to prove the point.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Who says it’s always the same project? Ahem, excuse me, “test”.

Comment: @DanBron Something tells me you've encountered one of these suspicious job posts.

Comment: @ATL_DEV Not me. Haven’t been a programmer in more than a decade. And now I’m sad at how old I am 

Comment: You could estimate how long it'll take you to complete, then quote them an hourly rate if it is more than a couple of hours.

Comment: Can you flag the job ad? I recall someone suggesting that in another meta post but maybe that was a feature request.

Comment: Note that if they are trying to get work done for free on the false pretences that there is a job at the end of it,  it is likely criminal, so if you really think there's a problem it may be worth contacting the relevant authorities in whichever country..

Comment: The SO Careers business model seems to be spamming irrelevant adverts to as many random people as possible, as opposed to serious careers sites that work with candidate matching. This in turn mostly attracts companies that aren't serious, as we can see again and again on meta. This guy yesterday had very similar concerns: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381125/should-employers-be-able-to-post-future-opportunity-jobs-when-they-have-no-ope.

Comment: Am I the only person confused by "remote with ... the perks of endless supply of sodas and a free lunch program" ? How does a remote position get free lunch? What, do they send you Pizza Hut vouchers?

Comment: @Josh Caswell yes they can and they not only survive, they live prosperously because the kob offer is always the same, but the test changes.

Comment: "I've applied to several times, but I never got a response." As a side-note, I wouldn't apply more than once (or perhaps twice) personally. Getting any rejection is not nice without adding chasing for it.

Comment: The description of the test project sounds very similar to one I was asked to do when applying for a remote position that was listed on SO. *But* I didn't think it was an attempt to get free development work.

Comment: @SteveBennett A lot of postings say "remote" when they in fact should say "we may allow you to work remotely 1 per..." (lifetime? Yeah, probably)

Answer (score 20):

I've had a similar experience with such companies. There is one company I kept applying to several times and received no response (till date).

I was beginning to think it was a hoax and that they are just there to clog up the pipe.

This is a problem without a solution. You can't really tell if the company you are applying for is simply looking for free labor or not.

I will suggest leaving an indelible mark on your code, e.g. making the repository public. But some companies will simply request that you keep it private. You can't also obfuscate the code because some companies will request that you make it understandable.

In the end, it boils down to you discerning good companies from bad ones. I don't know the process involved in posting a job on Stack Overflow, but I wish there were checks and balances in place.

Comment: interesting thought experiment - how to give your code to someone so it's understandable but non reusable. submit via online compilers is one idea. use obscure programming features maybe?

Comment: The problem is that they easily could say that to verify if you pass the test, the code must be understandable.. I've seen some people "marking" code with invisible chars, but it can be easily removed I guess. It's like in security, to be effective, it should be as costly in time to remove the marking/un-obfuscate than to code it yourself, or to change substantial part of it if made public in a repository to protect it

Comment: Guys, guys, you're making this too complicated.  Just write it in Perl!  Guaranteed unreadability.

Comment: @ScottCWilson Does Perl "*compile in Visual Studio 2017*"?

Answer (score 11):

Thanks for bringing this to our attention, and I'm sorry about the experience you had. The best thing to do in scenarios like this is to report the listing or the company so our team can investigate.

You can report specific job listings as follows:

[image]

We investigate every one of these reports to ensure that our customers follow our policy & guidelines and to maintain job quality. This includes making sure that the listing is about a specific opportunity (not an "evergreen" listing) and that applicants aren't mistreated.

For this specific case, please either report the listing or [message our support team directly](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) with the details so we can reach out to the customer and investigate the issue.

Answer (score 5):

> What can be done about job posters seeking to get free development work?

Likely nothing direct or immediate can be done, but it might help to provide a mechanism for users to attach comments / reviews / ratings to company profiles, especially if some kind of summary score can then be displayed with their ads.  Of course, such a thing would be open to the same kind of sock-puppetry and other manipulation as SE Q&A channels, but SE has devoted a fair amount of time and effort to developing means to detect and counteract such manipulation.

I suppose that such a mechanism might cut into revenue by discouraging scammers and sweatshops from using the service, but it also might make the service more valuable to legitimate employers by attracting more job-seekers and reducing noise.  I really don't know how the economics would fall out, but if it tends to improve the quality of job offerings then it will provide a better experience for all (remaining) participants.